# How to update converseen?

Tags: updates

I have been informed by the program that it needs an update but have no idea how to do this.  I have only installed Ubuntu this morning and have managed just about everything else but I am stumped with this one.

I have got a INSTALL file and it says this...

```
To compile Converseen you need Qt4, Magick++ development libraries, cmake and the gnu c++ compiler.
```

Download Converseen, extract the archive content, enter directory and build the executable using these commands:

```
tar -xvf converseen_0.x-tar.bz2
cd converseen_0.x
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
su
make install
```

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from the writers... :D

> Hi, unfortunately the new version of Converseen isn't available for Ubuntu 14.04 so you may need to wait until the maintainer of the package updates it.
>
> As a second option you might try to use the Ubuntu Handbook PPA that should contain the updated version of the program:
>   
>   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install converseen`

I hope this answers the question... not tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could just remove it and then reinstall it, that should work if you download straight from the offical website because it would download anything needed. Thats the first thing I try when problems arise and it works almost 90% of the time!

Comment: Unfortunately I loaded it from the software center because it is on there and have no idea how to install it from scratch... sorry very new to Linux

Comment: Ah, same here, have you tried just googling converseen ubuntu? Maybe reinstall from the software center... Let me know how it works out!

Comment: I have now asked the writer if they can help me with it as I tried a reinstall and no joy....  unfortunately the software center does not support this programs updates...  also did the update details from the website and that didn't work so something must be wrong...  hopefully they will upload the new version into the software centre which will help.. :D