# how to convert .svg image to .png?

Tags: image-processing, png, svg

I would like to change the color of some SVG pictures and then save them as PNG images. I have installed GIMP. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

- With GIMP, open the SVG, then use the *Export* action from the *File* menu (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>):

  [image: IMG:]
- Select PNG from the drop down menu or the *Select File Type* list:

  [image]
- Select appropriate settings and export:

  [image]

Comment: I wouldn't be confident using the GIMP to edit an SVG, though (as per OP's request).

Comment: I wouldn't use it to edit SVGs either, but it can convert well enough. And then edit the converted images.

Answer (score 1):

You could install [Inkscape](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/inkscape/), open your SVG file in it, do your edits, and use the `File > Export PNG image...` option (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>) to do the conversion.

This is my standard procedure, and it works flawlessly. How well it works for you might depend in the source for your SVG, but certainly worth trying.

It should be possible to do this with Image Magick, as [noted in another Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/695786/38585), but I always find that a bit trickier to control, and there's a bit of a learning curve there. It also appears that the "[Converseen](http://converseen.fasterland.net/)" front-end hasn't been updated for [Ubuntu 14+](https://askubuntu.com/q/497267/38585), and its website has issues (so far as I can see).